# How to remove "save&new" button from popup in odoo?

Tags: xml, popup, odoo, odoo-8

I have a `one2many` field, and when I click to create a new record, I have 2 buttons.

I want to remove the `"Save & New"` button and keep the `"Save & Close"` button.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you do not mind sleazy hacks.

In your form view you can try this. You may need to clear your cache before it works for you. This is only sensible if you do not want it to appear but its not really a security thing just for looks and process. You may need to ensure the class selector is correct for your version.

I tested this by placing it in the xml for the form view that appears, not in the xml for the form view that you are adding a new one2many record within. So to be clear this css needs to be in the form view that pops up and contains the "Save & New" button.

```
<style>
     .oe_abstractformpopup-form-save-new {
          display:none !important;
     }
</style>
```

Comment: upvoted, actually had another solution, but that was longer and involved overriding the base template for popup fields. css never came to mind :)

Comment: Thanks @danidee , sometimes we always find ourselves looking for a fancy solution when there is a solution right in front of us that is so dumb it just might work!

Comment: Thanks @phillipstack. It works like a sharm. Thanks for this easy solution.

Comment: Glad this helped you.

Comment: @PhillipStack I dont understand it clearly. Should I write this code in the view xml under the record tag before the form tag? Can you give me more information? Unfortunately, I never do same until now. If you want a new question topic for this I will create it.

Comment: In your xml anywhere inside the form tag should do.

Answer (score 1):

I know there's an option `disable_multiple_selection` that you can turn on/off to show/hide that button. I don't know if it's usable within a XML definition of a view/form/field but if this is not the case you could try to do it via JS.

This is the place https://github.com/OCA/OCB/blob/9.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/form_common.js#L854

Answer (score 0):

Try to give access of only write, remove access of create for the related form object.